# How do I get StringBuilder documentation back in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

For some inexplicable reason my NetBeans install 7.4 beta stopped showing the `StringBuilder` methods in my Java classes.
I haven't messed with anything at all it just stopped working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How to reproduce the problem in your case? I mean, what is your code and where the error apppears.

Answer (score 2):

Download the documentation from [Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs) if you want the documentation
for offline reference.

Go to the menu `Tools -> Java Platforms`. There you can select the
Java version you are using and then click on `Add Zip/Folder` on `javadoc`
tab and specify the path to the downloaded zip. Or click on `Add URL`and put `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs´.

**NOTE**: links are for Java 7 API.